# ヘルプセンターの記事「Be nice.」の和訳案、これでどうでしょうか

Tags: 討議

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)の記事一覧で、センタートップに位置している「[Be nice.](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)」の和訳案です。モデレーター陣でひととおり納得のいく内容にしてみましたが、ちょっと頭をひねっているところもあり、修正案など寄せていただけるとうれしいです。

[image: スクリーンショット]

頭をひねっているところ:

- 「親切に」は積極的に行動をおこしましょう、という感じがします。この記事は「コミュニケーションをとる時はこういうところに気をつけましょう」のように、受け身とはいわないまでも、おせっかいになりかねない積極的な親切とは違う内容のように思われます。といっても端的にしっくりくる表現が思い浮かばず...「大人な対応」「紳士的」?

以下、タイトルと本文です。

---

## 親切になろうポリシー

質問をするためにこのサイトを訪れた人も、知識を惜しみなく共有しに来たという人も、スタックオーバーフローは共に学ぶための場所であるということを忘れないでおきましょう。皆を温かく迎え、知識があなたよりもちょっと少ない人へはとりわけ辛抱強くありましょう。あ、それから、ユーモアをお忘れなく。

以下３つのガイドラインをご参照ください：

1. **相手を軽視するような無礼な言葉遣いは好ましくありません。** 互いに敬意を払う相手と実際に顔を合わせて話しているような口調であるべきです。丁寧な言葉遣いで投稿する時間がない場合は投稿せず、時間があり丁寧にコメントできる他のユーザーに委ねましょう。
2. **新しいユーザーを常に温かく迎え、やや辛抱強く、そして相手の善意を前提としましょう。** 新しいユーザーはスタックオーバーフローのルールや仕組みをよく知らないかもしれません。サイトに慣れるまで、優しく辛抱強く見守ってあげましょう。助けを求めてここに来た時は、他の人があなたを手助けしやすいよう気を配りましょう。ここにいる皆はボランティアです。横柄な態度で助けを一方的に要求されたりしては誰しも応じにくいものです。
3. **意地悪など心ない行動はやめましょう。** 以下の通りいくつかの例をあげますので見かけた場合はすぐに[通報してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)：

   - **個人に対する批評。** 投稿者ではなく投稿内容に焦点を当ててください。投稿に対する批評であっても個人へのあてつけと取れる表現（手抜き、無知、不機嫌など）も含みます。
   - **あらゆる偏見。** 人種や性別、性的指向、宗教などに基づき個人やグループを攻撃するような言葉は許されません。これらはいくつかの例であり、判別がつきかねる言葉自体許されません。
   - **不適切な言葉。** 下品な言葉や性的な暗示を含むものを避けましょう。出会い系サイトではありません。
   - **嫌がらせやいじめ。** 敵対的なやりとりを見つけた場合は[通報ください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)。敵対的行為が継続する場合は一旦そこから離れ、他のユーザーやモデレーターにまかせましょう。スタッフが注意すべき案件については各ページの下部にある[お問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)リンクからご連絡ください。

ユーザー主導型のオンラインコミュニティとして、スタックオーバーフローには悪口や嫌がらせ、その他オンラインで見かける意地悪な投稿がほとんど存在しないことを誇りに思います。そして今後、そうあり続けられるかどうかは私たち次第です。

**以上です。互いに親切に、スタックオーバーフローを居心地のいい場所にしていきましょう。**

Comment: 原文のもとになったメタ投稿: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: タイトルに関してですが、この"Be"は「なる・なろう」では無く、「〜であれ」みたいなニュアンスではないでしょうか。あと今のだと"Be nice"のシンプルさや、とっつきやすさがない気がします。で、ふつうに"Be nice"を訳すと「なかよく」とかになるのでしょうが、これもおかしいですし、特に良い案があるわけではありません。

Comment: ヘルプセンター記事[「気持ちよく参加するために」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)で「思いやりを持ちましょう」と訳されているセクションを詳しく書いたものなので、これと訳を揃えるのは手かもしれません。あるいは /help/be-nice を「気持ちよく参加するために」にして、/help/behavior を別のタイトルにするとか。/help/behavior の Be nice. 以外のセクションは気持ちよく参加するためにというより、単にこのサイトで守ってほしいことのようにも見えますし。

Comment: 適用しました：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice