# 行動規範を促進するためのバナーを表示させませんか？

Tags: 討議, 完了, 行動規範

行動規範の広報についてリクエストがあり、それについての賛成意見が多く見られたため、日本語版の行動規範バナーを表示できればと思います。

1. 確認のため、日本語版の行動規範バナー表示に賛成の方はこちらの投稿に投票いただけますでしょうか m_ _m。
2. バナーの表示テキストは以下の通りです。

   > 最新の[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)をもって、親切で居心地の良い学習コミュニティを共に作ろうではありませんか。
   >   (Join us in building a kind and comfortable learning community via our updated Code of Conduct の和訳です。)
3. 可能な方は、行動規範の和訳の修正がないかを今一度ご確認ください。
   和訳：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct
   英語本文：https://stackoverflow.com/conduct
   和訳の修正をご自身で行える場合は https://ja.traducir.win/をご使用ください。
   ご参考までに[Be nice policy](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2430/%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B-be-nice-%E3%81%AE%E5%92%8C%E8%A8%B3%E6%A1%88-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B) をご覧ください。

追記：バナー表示期間は10/25-11/24です。

Comment: とても個人的な意見なのでスルーでいいですけど、「〜しようではありませんか」は強い言い方で強制圧力を感じます。（扇動というかなんというか）政治家がよく使う言葉だからでしょうか？

Comment: @Sieg 今回のバナー表示テキスト修正案受付期間は10/10-22でしたが、ぜひ次回以降また提案がございましたらよろしくお願い致します！

Answer (score 0):

送信日：11月15日
今回につきましては**日本語版サイトのみ**に登録されているユーザーのみなさまへJ-CoCメールが送信されました。（本家などの英語サイトにも登録されている方へはJ-CoCメールを送ることができませんでした。申し訳ありません！）

元のメール(英文)
[スクリーンショットはこちら](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7T4T.png)

---

件名：
より良いコミュニティを作り上げるために - 新しい行動規範をご覧ください

本文：
最新の行動規範をもって、親切で居心地の良い学習コミュニティを共に作りましょう。

[行動規範を読む](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

いつもスタック・オーバーフロー、および Stack Exchange Network をご利用いただきありがとうございます。

この度、Stack Exchange コミュニティでの話し合いをもとに行動規範の改定を行いました。**行動規範**とは「コミュニティにおいて行動する際に守るべきルール」で、ユーザーの皆さんがお互いに敬意を表し、さらに居心地の良い環境を整えるために行動規範の作成を手伝ってくれたのです。新たに更新された行動規範を是非ご覧ください。

いくつかのハイライトをご紹介します：

- **助けを求めてここに来た場合には、他の人があなたを手助けしやすいよう気を配りましょう**。ガイドラインに従いましょう。そして私たちのコミュニティはボランティアの支えによって存在していることを忘れないでおきましょう。
- **フィードバックをする時には明確で建設的に、そしてフィードバックを受ける時には寛容な態度で受け止めましょう**。編集やコメント、提案はコミュニティの健全な一面なのです。
- **親切でフレンドリーな態度を心がけましょう。皮肉な言葉は避け、冗談にも気をつけてください。** オンライン上ではそれらのトーンを解釈し辛いものです。フレンドリーな態度を保ち辛い場合は一度そこから離れて心を切り替え、次に進んでください。
- **有害な内容を通報してください。** 内容にもよりますが、通報はモデレーターに注意を喚起し、時には自動削除をもたらすこともあります

[行動規範を読む](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

ご協力ありがとうございます。

Comment: タイトルから強制していくのは度が強い気がするので、「新しい行動規範を遵守してください」→「新しい行動規範をご覧ください」とするのはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 英語をストレートに翻訳すると日本語で受ける印象がだいぶお硬い感じなので、うまくクッションに包めるといいのかなと思います。また、そもそも「行動規範」という言葉自体に馴染みのない人も多いと思うので、簡単な説明を1行程度で付け加えられるとよさそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 変更いたしました :)

Comment: @cubick   行動規範（コミュニティで行動する際に守るべきルール）とし、「みなさん、どーもこんにちは！」を追加しました。いかがでしょうか？全体的にクッションに包むような柔らかな日本語に変更すべきであれば、どうぞご編集くださいませ！

Comment: オープンマインドは訳して欲しいです。

Comment: @Sieg  メール本文は抜粋のため、行動規範自体の変更となりますが、以下でよろしいでしょうか？

「そしてフィードバックを受ける時にはオープンマインドを心がけましょう」
->
「そしてフィードバックを受ける時には耳を傾け視野を広く持つよう心がけましょう」

Comment: 案として「(おおらか|寛容)な態度で受け止めましょう」

Comment: 「そしてフィードバックを受ける時には寛容な態度で受け止めましょう。」に、メールドラフトおよびCoC(@traducir)にて変更いたしました！